# How to display progress column in Java Table

Tags: java, swing, jtable, progress-bar, tablecellrenderer

So I am creating a project which has three columns; one is a check box column the second one is string (words form a neo4j database) and the third for progress bars.

All the columns are displayed and work fine but the progress bar column is invisible as it seems. Here is some code:

```
    //CONSTRUCTOR
        public BiogramTableJSedit2Jan9()
        {   
            //*************************************************
            //* SETTING UP THE FORM                      *                                          
            //*************************************************
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setBounds(200,200,800,300);
            setTitle("Netword Data Table");
            getContentPane().setLayout(null);

            //*************************************************


        //********************************************
                //CREATING TABLE BLOCK                       *
                //********************************************

                //ADD SCROLLPANE
                JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane();
                scroll.setBounds(70,80,600,200);
                getContentPane().add(scroll);

                //THE TABLE
                final JTable table=new JTable();
                scroll.setViewportView(table);


                //THE MODEL OF THE TABLE
                DefaultTableModel model=new DefaultTableModel()  
                {
                    //****************************************
                    //* SETTING TABLE COLUMNS BLOCK          * 
                    //****************************************
                    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column)  
                    {
                        switch(column)
                        {
                        case 0:                             // |This is the first column
                            return Boolean.class;           // |First column is set to Boolean as it will contain check boxes
                        case 1:                             // |This is the second column
                            return String.class;            // |Second column set to String as it will contain strings
                        case 2:
                            return JProgressBar.class;      // |This is for the progress bar column (IN PROGRESS - NOT DISPLAYED YET...) 

                        default:
                            return String.class;            // |The table is set to String as default 
                        }
                    }
                };


                //Create and run the query in the table         
                neoQuery= Q1();
                resultVariable = session.run(neoQuery.get());   



                //ASSIGN THE MODEL TO TABLE 
                table.setModel(model);

                model.addColumn("Select");                  // |Column for check boxes
                model.addColumn("Bigrams");                 // |Column for Bigrams

                table.getColumn("Status").setCellRenderer(new ProgressCellRender());

                //**********************************************
ProgressWorker worker = new ProgressWorker(model); //HAVE AN ERROR HERE
worker.execute();
```

This is the progress renderer class:

```
//a table cell renderer that displays a JProgressBar
public class ProgressCellRender extends JProgressBar implements TableCellRenderer {

  @Override
  public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
      int progress = 0;
      if (value instanceof Float) {
          progress = Math.round(((Float) value) * 100f);
      } else if (value instanceof Integer) {
          progress = (int) value;
      }
      setValue(progress);
      return this;
  }
}
```

Now you can see that I am using getColumn in order to display this column but when I run it you can see the first and second but not the progress bar column. I want it to look similar to this:

[image: JTable with progress bar column example]

I also has a progress worker class that is not fully implemented.

```
private static class ProgressWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Integer> 
    { //Swing worker class for updating the progress bar

        private BiogramTableJSedit2Jan9 model;

        private final JProgressBar progress; //declaration for progress bar

        public ProgressWorker(JProgressBar model)
        { 
            this.progress = model;

        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

            return null;
        }
```

I would appreciate if anyone can explain to me why the thirst column is not being displayed. Thanks for any replies in advance.

Comment: Your example is broken, we don't have your database and your methods that fill your `DefaultTableModel` will not work for us. Code you provided doesn't seem to fill the model with data at all. If I create dummy `TableModel` with dummy data and set the `ProgressCellRender` as a cell renderer it displays properly.

Comment: Sorry I cannot provide some code as it contains confidential data

Comment: I don't mind an example with random data

Comment: In your `DefaultTableModel.getColumnClass` method you should not return `JProgressBar.class`, but instead `Integer.class`or `Float.class`.
Otherwise, in your  `ProgressCellRenderer.getTableCellRendererComponent` method
none of your `if` clauses would get activated and `progress` would stay `0`.

Comment: Thank you, I will try this. That was one thing I was not so sure about.

Comment: I think that is one mistake corrected, but the column is still invisible.

Comment: Then there is still another problem, probably in the code not shown. May be the table data in the "Progress" column have the wrong type.

Comment: I did have an error here so I commented it out //ProgressWorker worker = new ProgressWorker(model);
       // worker.execute(); This was right after the table.getColumn etc. line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your posted code was not self-contained I set up a minimal test together
with your already posted `ProgressCellRender` class.

The important bugfix is in method `getColumnClass` of the `DefaultTableModel`.
It needs to return `Integer.class` or `Float.class` because only those can be
handled by your `ProgressCellRender`.

And of course, the actual data in that column need to be `Integer` or `Float`.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Main::initGUI);
    }

    private static void initGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableModel JProgressBar Demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane();
        frame.getContentPane().add(scroll);

        final JTable table = new JTable();
        scroll.setViewportView(table);

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel() {
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
                switch (column) {
                case 0:
                    return Boolean.class;
                case 1:
                    return String.class;
                case 2:
                    return Integer.class;  // !!!!
                default:
                    return String.class;
                }
            }
        };
        table.setModel(model);

        model.addColumn("Active");
        model.addColumn("Name");
        model.addColumn("Progress");

        table.getColumn("Progress").setCellRenderer(new ProgressCellRender());

        model.addRow(new Object[] { true, "aaaa", 14 });
        model.addRow(new Object[] { false, "bbbbbbbb", 0 });
        model.addRow(new Object[] { true, "ccccc", 2 });

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Then the `JProgressBar`s are rendered correctly in the table:

[image]

In your `ProgessCellRender` you may want to add `setStringPainted(true);` to get the percentage also rendered as text.

Comment: Thank you this was useful but I have another problem. So basically I had a button in this frame but by using initGUI and swing utilities the button is not showing up. Is there a way to move the table down a little and add a button above it?

Comment: @DavidGardener If you have another problem, please open a new question.